# How to refer to a site using hostname

Tags: alternate-access-mapping, dns

1. Created 2 Virtual (1 for AD and other one for SP)
2. AD installed (w2k8) and added all the necessary sp users.
3. Just finished installing sharepoint 2010. CA config is done.
4. I can access my sharepoint by typing http://machinename or http://machinename:3500 for CA

I would like to configure it where I want to type portal.mysp.test. I tried adding alternate mapping and added a dns cname but dont know if that correct way of doing this or not. because I can't get the portal.mysp.test to resolve.

Answer (score 5):

As a Best Practice, you never want to reference your SharePoint installation using the machine name so you are on the right track.

1. Add "portal.mysp.test" to your DNS
2. Add "portal.mysp.test" as the name of your Default or Intranet zone in SharePoint
3. You might need to also add "portal.mysp.test" as a host header to your SharePoint web application in IIS.  SharePoint
   sometimes does this and sometimes does not

Once that is done, you should be able to access your farm using that url from anywhere in your organization.

Comment: 1. Added A record in DNS (portal.site.com with target machine's IP Address)
2. Added Alternate Access Mappings "http://portal.site.com" with default zone and public url for zone is http://portal.site.com
3. Went to IIS and clicked on SharePoint-80 web application and clicked on Bindings and added portal.site.com On the WFE server when I type portal.site.com it prompts me username n pass. I put in user n pass but a blank page shows up. On client pc I type portal.site.com and google suggest there is no site for this address. but I can type the http://machinename on client's browser and team site

Comment: Does your client pc use the DNS in which the a-record is created? If so, did you flush the dns? On the WFE you might be denied access because of the loopbackcheck: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861

Comment: If you are seeing the google page then it means that the PC is not using the DNS server that you are updating.  If you do an ipconfig /all does it list the proper DNS server?

Comment: @DaveWise: I am running ad and sp on VMWare workstation. and my pc is not part of the vm-ad. however, I added a entry in the host file 192.168.xx.xxx and portal.site.com but not able to access portal.site.com. I can however access the portal.site.com from the wfe after making an entry by Dribbel post.